# Display content based on ids stored in localstorage (API request)

Tags: angular, api

I've hit a wall trying to create a function which I think has made me dumber.
I've made an imdb clone with the help of the tmdb API and now I'd like to make a function where you can add your favorites to a list. Currently, I have managed to add/remove a movie in an array(basically, the id gets stored in the array) and it also gets stored in localstorage.
I have this function in the compnent where you can find the movies:

```
  toggleFavoriteBtn(id: number) {
    let clickedMovie = this.movies$.find(movie => movie.id === id);
    if (clickedMovie.favourite) {
      // unfavourite
      this.favoritesArray = this.favoritesArray.filter(fave => fave !== id);
    } else {
      this.favoritesArray.push(id);
    }
    clickedMovie.favourite = !clickedMovie.favourite;
    localStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify(this.favoritesArray));
  }
}
```

movies$ (movies$: Movie[];) is pretty much a model (turned into an array) which helps me pull out the APIs, as you an see I have made the API requests in this way in my service:

```
  getMovieDetails(id: number) {
    return this._http.get<Movie[]>(`${this.movieDetailURL}/${id}`, {
      params: {
        api_key: API_KEY,
        append_to_response: "release_date,images,similar,credits"
      }
    });
  }
```

So what I would like to do now is be able to display the fave movies in a different component with the help of the getMovieDetails function, but I just simply can't wrap my head around how. I think I've watched too many tutorials and ended up very confused...
This is what I've got so far:

```
export class FavoritesListComponent implements OnInit {
  favouriteMovies: Movie[];
  results = [];
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // get the favourites[] from localStorage
    if (localStorage.getItem("favorites") === null) {
      this.favouriteMovies = [];
    } else {
      this.favouriteMovies = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favorites"));
    }
    this.favouriteMovies.forEach(
      movie => {
        // const movie = this.dataService.getMovieDetails(id);
        // this.results = this.favouriteMovies.push(movie);
        this.dataService.getMovieDetails(movie.id);
      }
      // .subscribe(movie => this.favouriteMovies.push(movie))
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of combining observables using `forkJoin` or `combineLatest` or you can do it using a simple `for` loop.

I will show you simple `for` loop. Instead of the `forEach`, do this. You can do it using `forEach` as well, I just prefer `for` loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i < favouriteMovies.length; i++) {
  this.dataService.getMovieDetails(favouriteMovies[i].id).subscribe(movieDetails => {
    console.log(movieDetails);
  });
}
```

If you want me to show you the `forkJoin` or `combineLatest` way I can as well but that should be enough to get you unblocked.

Comment: Thank you very much! It did indeed get me unblocked. To be 100% honest, I think the core issue with me is that I haven't grasped what .subscribe() really does and when to apply it, but just managed to use it so far with trial and error. The same goes honestly for .find(), .filter() etc. One day I'll get it.